# CMD doesn't wait to finish process

Tags: cmd, windows-7

When i use command

```
<path exc.xlsx>
```

it starts excel file working and wait until i close the file than i can type next command. My issue is that when other excel file is running cmd doesn't wait to close the file and goes to next line. It is necessary to type the command that will force cmd to wait until i close excel file even when onother excel file is running. I tried a lot of commands from the internet but no one seems to work properly. These were for instance:

```
start /wait  exc.xlsx && exit
exc.xlsx  cmd /k
exc.xlsx|rem
```

I'm using Windows7.

Comment: It might be possible to configure Excel to load each document in a separate process, I don't remember.  That's the only possible solution.  If a document doesn't have a dedicated process, there's no way for the command interpreter to tell when you've closed it.

Comment: I cant find the excel proces even when only one file is opened. I did a simple script in python which works in the loop and try to change name of the file. When it can change the name it means that the file is closed but sometimes the script seems to be stuck and cant open my excel file.

Answer (score 0):

I try this method but it sometimes doesn't work properly. The line `<os.rename>` try to change name of the file. If it can it means that the file is closed and break the loop but using that the script sometimes can't open the excel file. I'm not as advanced as i would be and cant find another way to check if the file is closed.

```
import os
def is_open(file_name):
   if os.path.exists(file_name):
      while True:

          try:
                os.rename(file_name, file_name)  
                break
          except:
                continue
      time.sleep(0.001)
is_open('exc.xlsx')
```

That's not very dignified and uses a lot of processor.  If there is a way using programing language (preferably python) I can implement that in my script.